# Call set_pose service of robot_localization

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i'm trying to call the set_pose service provided from robot_localization node,  from console.
It expects a posewithcovatiancestamped type message.
If I type: rosservice call /set_pose "{}", the tf is set to 0,0,0.
But What If I need to set another pose?

Service arguments are: [pose.header.seq pose.header.stamp pose.header.frame_id pose.pose.pose.position.x pose.pose.pose.position.y pose.pose.pose.position.z pose.pose.pose.orientation.x pose.pose.pose.orientation.y pose.pose.pose.orientation.z pose.pose.pose.orientation.w pose.pose.covariance]

I tried things like:

- rosservice call /summit_a/set_pose "[0 now /odom_ekf_frame 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]" but i don't find the key for this call.
  Thanks in advance and best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198438/call-set_pose-service-of-robot_localization/) by [ASoriano](https://answers.ros.org/users/20687/asoriano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2014-11-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tab completion works:

```
rosservice call /set_pose (now press tab)
```

yields

```
rosservice call /set_pose "pose:
  header:
    seq: 0
    stamp:
      secs: 0
      nsecs: 0
    frame_id: ''
  pose:
    pose:
      position: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}
      orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0}
    covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]"
```

Just fill out those values with the values you want.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4